# Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma And Integral Having $\sin(\cdot)$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous and absolutely integrable. The formulation of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma which I am given is $$\lim_{\omega \to \infty}\int_a^bf(t)e^{i\omega t}dt=0.$$ It is taken from 'Integral Transforms and Their Applications' by Brian Davies. Later on, he claims that $$\lim_{\omega \to \infty} \int_a^b f(t)\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{t}dt=\lim_{\omega \to \infty} \int_b^\infty f(t)\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{t}=0$$ follows from the lemma ($b>a>0$). However, I fail to see why this is the case. I'd be even more glad, if there is a elementary way to show this without using the lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Set $\frac{f(t)}{t} = g(t)$ and observe that 
$$\lim_{w \to \infty}\int_{a}^{b} g(t)e^{i w t} = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try it tomorrow. I thought about using euler, too. However I thought that the integral might only evaluate to zero because sin and cos cancel each other and that it is not possible to say that both integral, I.e. one with sine one with cosine are equal to zero

Comment: @Deavor Remember that $e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta) + \color{red}{i} \sin(\theta)$. The real part does not 'cancel' the imaginary part.